# How do I programmatically create a dynamically color changing gradient in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, dynamic, sprite-kit, gradient, uicolor

I'm trying to create a gradient background for in spritekit. I am able to create basic gradient backgrounds with two colors but I want to create a gradient background that keeps on changing colors automatically.
I'm relatively new to swift.

I'm trying to create [**something like this**](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/DCQfWlUr0nbaNpPTBy)
the gradient should act the way the gif acts. colors changing automatically, adjustable direction. etc

Thanks for your help fellow developers.

Comment: you can use this [awesome library](https://github.com/cruisediary/Pastel)

Comment: I am trying to use pastel as a background for my spritekit scene. can you please guide me through it. i have tried altering zposition in the scene and by changing the insert at property of subview but nothing works .

Comment: open a new thread with your codes and show the community what you have done so far.